# PHP for loop working in command line execution but not in web browser

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I have tried an activity to check if a

**> FOR/WHILE LOOP**

fails or not if it loop through a few million records ....

**My Activity**

I have more than 1000000 records in a table and if i fetch them and print them

through a for loop and executed this script it with command line it worked successfully..

but when i tried it in a web browser it stucks and closed my browser...

So I want to know is it a failure of  **PHP**(obviously not as it worked in command line)..

or It is a failure of **WEB SERVER???**

What to do if i must have such a situation in real time web application??

Should I switch to a more powerfull web server if yes then Which One...??

Comment: `in real time web application`, there is none. Your never want to print millions of rows, heard of pagination?

Comment: what if i will need to combine data from multiple tables join is useless because i need to fetch/process those records manually because they have special operations to perform...obviously i will not print million of records  but i need to count them(for getting number of pages) for that it requires same loop...i understand it is little undigestable but it is the only way i can do so... anyway thanks...

Comment: to get around that you only return what you want from the dataset, for getting total count for pagination you do a `SELECT COUNT..` you **dont** get all the rows then count them in php.

Comment: i have to perform some special logical filters on records so in that case i cannot use SQL's where operation so COUNT will not work in this scenario.

Comment: So its really just an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because your not able to optimise's sql querys on your non-normalized dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're running into the max execution time limit which is unlimited on the command line but has a default of 30s on the web server. Try adding the following line at the beginning of your script to remove the limit:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

From the official php [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

> **max_execution_time**
>
> This sets the maximum time in seconds a
> script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This
> helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The
> default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the
> default setting is 0.

Comment: Thank you for such a useful information it worked for atleast 1 million records (i tried). Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print 1 000 000 records to browser, you gonna have a bad time...

First - what FuzzyTree said - execution time. But if you say that it works in `cli` I guess that's not the problem.

Problem with this amount of data is probably browser, which simply cannot handle that much! Check out your `CPU` and `RAM` usage while trying to visit that page.

If you REALLY need to display user million of records, use pagination or load new records when user reach bottom of the page using `ajax`.